# When generated an Apache CXF client, why is the WSDL still needed when instantiating the client?

Tags: java, apache, wsdl, cxf

I want to consume a SOAP service but the WSDL is provided to me offline, thus resulting in the client being generated with the local path to the WSDL.

```
public class SoSo extends Service {
    public final static URL WSDL_LOCATION;
    public final static QName SERVICE = new QName("http://tempuri.org/", "SoSo");
    public final static QName SoSoSoap12 = new QName("http://tempuri.org/", "SoSoSoap12");
    public final static QName SoSoSoap = new QName("http://tempuri.org/", "SoSoSoap");
    static {
        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL("file:/c:/Dev/Java/workspace/service-individualreport/src/main/resources/wsdl/SoSo.wsdl");
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(SoSo.class.getName())
                .log(java.util.logging.Level.INFO, 
                 "Can not initialize the default wsdl from {0}", "file:/c:/Dev/Java/workspace/service-individualreport/src/main/resources/wsdl/SoSo.wsdl");
    }
    WSDL_LOCATION = url;
}
```

From my point of view I would like to only build the WSDL once and then specify the location of the service.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Couple parts to this question:

1) Per JAX-WS spec, the generated code doesn't have *ALL* the information needed for the request.  Thus, the wsdl is technically needed.   With CXF, you CAN pass "null" for the wsdl URL and then use the ((BindingProvider)port).getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, "http://localhost/....") to set the address and for many use cases, it will work.

2) The wsdl2java tool does have a -wsdlLocation flag that can be used to generate service objects with specific locations.  -wsdlLocation ""  should result in nothing burned into the code.   The code wouldn't really be portable then though.  (JAXWS ri/metro requires the wsdl)